# Android Firebase retrieve all data in single path and store it in SQLite

Tags: android, sqlite, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

How to retrieve all the data in a single path and store it in SQLite?
I found out that it would be really difficult to me to filter the data in `searchView` therefore I come up the idea of retrieving the data from firebase and store it in SQLite to filter or search in view.

I think it is possible but what is the easy way to do it?
[image: it is the path]

How to paste the each "Account" from firebase to SQLite?

Comment: A couple of things. This is a fairly simple task; read in each firebase node as strings, create a row in SQL and write the strings out. So what have you tried? Do you have any code you are having difficulties with? The other thing is that it be be a lot *less* work to refactor and/or denormalize your Firebase data so you can perform the queries without a two or three step process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
// get currently logged in user uid
FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();

// you can do filtering here to make sure user object is not null

// get the data by using addListenerForSingleValueEvent
FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Account/" + user.getUid)
    .addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        ... onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            for (DataSnapshot snapshot: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                // do SQLite insertion for each data here
            }
        }
        ...
    });
```

> I assume you are familiar with SQLite, so I don't include code about it there

We use `addListenerForSingleValueEvent()` because it only request data from Firebase Database once. Unlike `addValueEventListener()`. Here is [the official documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write)

---

**EDIT**

It looks like I misunderstand, the above code is used to request data from `Account/randomUserId`, but the op is asking to request data from `Account`. So we don't need to get `FirebaseUser` anymore, and replace line above to this:

```
FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Account")
    .add ...
```

Comment: Thanks for answer my question. However, why get Current user? Since SQLite only store locally in device. Then other devices might not see the data

Comment: It is userID but what if i want to display 10+ account?

Comment: In the foreach, is it `datasnapshot.getchildren()`?

Comment: Oh yes it should be that, my bad